form.io datasource's "Trigger on Form init" feature using vanilla js
While working on pdf forms on formio portal. While exploring, I came across the data source component and found out an interesting feature - Trigger on form init. 
A crucial usecase of this trigger is - When form.io pdf form loads in edit mode, form.io's framework handles pre-population of submitted data. And the js written in the data-source component gets executed after data pre-populations is finished.


Now here is my scenario - 

I m using a hidden field instead of data source for some reason.
For this hidden fields there is some associated js code that needs to be executed only when formio pdf form is opened in edit mode.
The complicated part is this js must be executed after formio has handled pre-population for submitted form's data, when loading form in edit mode.
I figured out that this feature of formio data source components - Trigger on form init serves the purpose, but due to some restrictions I cannot use it.

So is there a clean way, I can implement this form.io's Trigger on form init functionality using vanilla js ?
